# Migrate from CVS to Mercurial: Separating projects

Tags: mercurial, cvs

We have a CVS repository with years of development history and 3 projects under one project (CVS folder). Those should be different repositories in a Mercurial repo. They are in the following scheme:

Project
---Sub Project 1
---Sub Project 2
---Sub Project 3

1. Is there a way to automate this during the cvs2hg process?
2. If not, what would be the Mercurial process to separate each sub project while keeping history (if possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply run cvs2hg three times, each time pointing it at a project subdirectory within your CVS repository; e.g.,

```
cvs2hg [OTHER-OPTIONS...] $CVSROOT/Project/SubProject1
```

Write the results into three separate Mercurial repositories.

Answer (score 6):

The best way to do this is to convert the entire repository from CVS to mercurial and then use the `hg convert` command with a `--filemap` to convert that single mercurial repo into multiple mercurial repos (convert will convert from hg to hg).  Your filemap will say something like:

```
include SubProject1
rename SubProject1 .
```

That will throw away everything that's not in sub project one and then move subproject one to the top (notice that trailing dot).

If you run that with a filemap for each of your sub projects, each time with the full repo as input, you'll end up with exactly what you want.

Some people have built shell scripts to do this, but if it's really just 3 of them it should be pretty quick.

Comment: Both options seems to be equivalent at the end but the buttom one seems cleaner. Yours probably will have extra history entries on the Mercurial version of the repository.

Comment: It won't.  A revision gets dropped if it has no more files.